# grep + sed for find & replace fun!

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, sed, find-and-replace

I have a dev copy of a website set up that has quite a few hardcoded references to its live counterpart.

I would like to replace all occurrences of "www." with "dev." in all files.

I think I can use a combination of grep + sed, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Lol it's not programing question. It's basic power user skill.

Comment: @Maciek: I can buy that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first try to used sed on one file its `sed 's/foo/bar/g'` for replacing foo with bar.
Then instead of grep i suggest find. Use it to find all files that need changes (*.php, *.html, etc...). Then find have -exec option.

Please make backup of Your project before You start.

Comment: Use `sed 's/foo/bar/g'` for a global replace.

Comment: Thanks. You are 100% right. with out it in only replace only first instance in a line. I edited my answerer.

Comment: I'm trying something like this with no success so far:
find . -name '*.html' -exec sed 's/www/dev/g' {} \;

Comment: FYI I ended up using:

find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/www\./dev\./g'